Which ID is correct for parenting an extension to the right-click menu via the VSIX .vsct file?
Repeatedly defining styles in WPF development can be monotonous so i'm making a VSIX to automate converting in-line style definitions into page style resources. Yet finding the ID needed for placing the command is proving diffiuclt.
I have been unable to find the correct ID needed in the .VSCT file, by default extensions appear in "IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" but ideally i'd like the command to appear as a member of the right-click menu that appears when in the XAML text editor (screenshot below). I've tried a multitude of other potential options as the ID that seem logical, but i have been unable to make it appear in that menu. Other forum posts have got commands to appear in the solution explorer when right-clicking, but this is an in-editor extension.
Right-click menu
